# Companies with Visa Sponsored for a non-European citizen

Tags: visa, citizenship

I'm a non-European citizen considering looking for jobs in Europe. Actually I'm Iranian, And as far as I know, some companies offer visa sponsorship to foreign candidates in Stack-Over-Flow.

But there is a problem, the process of getting a visa in my country (Iran) is too difficult, for example the Germany embassy in Iran gives people an appointment time more than one-two years, and the queue is too long.

I want to know if a company with sponsorship visa accepted me after an interview, do they have lawyers or legal processes to issue a visa for me or makes these queue easier?

And what exactly does VISA-SPONSORED mean? (specifically for users like me).

Comment: This is not a forum for general job advice. The question is too broad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, "visa sponsorship" usually means the company:

- **Will provide proof** of employment to their government. In some cases they will submit it, in others they'll send it to you to submit.
- **Is legally allowed to "host" you.** There are different types of companies and not all of them can employ foreign nationals.
- **Is willing** to go through this process. Other companies may not want to due to expenses and waiting time involved and the risk of you not receiving a visa or leaving the company.

**Typically:**

- You need a job offer to be able to apply for a work visa and permit.

  So sponsorship is more about enabling this process rather than improving it.

- The company can't make the application process go any faster.

  The company probably won't even be able to help much with your visa application in your home country (apart from providing proof of employment), but they might help with other relocation issues (such as any visa- or permit-related issues after entering their country as well as flights and accommodation).

- You may be able to get an appointment sooner when you're applying for a work visa as opposed to, for example, a holiday visa.
- In some cases you may be able to get a visa to enter a country to search for a job (Germany, for example, has a Job Seeker visa), which will allow you to go through the visa application process *now* and start working soon after you get an offer.

  You're presumably significantly less likely to get this type of visa.

- Few, if any, companies would be willing to wait much more than 6 months (if that much) for a new employee.

  But some companies may offer remote work in addition to visa sponsorship, which could allow you to work remotely at first and then move later.

**Note:**

All of this will heavily depend on the specific countries and company involved, in addition to possibly your career, qualification and expected salary. You'll need to do some reading up if you want a more specific answer.

In the EU specifically, there is a **["Blue Card"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_Card_(European_Union))** work permit, which may expedite the visa or permit application process, so that might be worth looking into. This also depends on the factors mentioned above.